# React - Clicking of link doesn't cause re-rendering of table

Tags: javascript, rest, reactjs

***This component makes a REST API call and parses promise value and renders the data in the form of a table.
load(function) makes the API call and takes orderType as input. OrderType is passed as a query parameter from the navigation component which is not included here.

---

```
class SampleController extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        let orderType = this.props.location.query.orderType;
        this.load = this.load.bind(this);
        this.load(orderType);
        this.state = {orderType: orderType, data: null}
    }


 load(orderType) {
    let self = this;
    console.log("order type is" + orderType);
    let baseURL = base_urls.orderMetricsBaseURL;
    console.log("base URL is", baseURL);
    let url = baseURL + "/getData";


    let response_data = fetch(url, {
                 method: 'POST',
                 headers: {
                   'Accept': 'application/json',
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 },
                 body: JSON.stringify({
                   order_type: orderType
                 })
             })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        let order_data = responseJson;
        console.log("responseeeeee is: ", order_data);
        self.setState({data: order_data});
        self.forceUpdate();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
     var content = <DataTable dataList = {this.state.data} />;
     return (
        content
    );
  }
}

export { SampleController as default };
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState()` does not update the state immediately, so there's a chance you are losing that update because of the `forceUpdate()`, which shouldn't be needed as `setState()` will trigger a re-render by itself. Try removing the `forceUpdate()` call.

Update:

In case you want to call your `load()` method each time your `orderType` you'd need to subscribe to the [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentWillreceiveprops) method.

Example:

```
class SampleController extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    let orderType = this.props.location.query.orderType;
    this.load = this.load.bind(this);
    this.load(orderType);
    this.state = {orderType: orderType, data: null}
  }

 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   const orderType = nextProps.location.query.orderType;
   const prevOrderType = this.props.location.query.orderType;

   if (prevOrderType !== orderType) {
     this.load(orderType);
   }
 }

 load(orderType) {
    let self = this;
    console.log("order type is" + orderType);
    let baseURL = base_urls.orderMetricsBaseURL;
    console.log("base URL is", baseURL);
    let url = baseURL + "/getData";


    let response_data = fetch(url, {
                 method: 'POST',
                 headers: {
                   'Accept': 'application/json',
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 },
                 body: JSON.stringify({
                   order_type: orderType
                 })
             })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        let order_data = responseJson;
        console.log("responseeeeee is: ", order_data);
        self.setState({data: order_data});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
     var content = <DataTable dataList = {this.state.data} />;
     return (
        content
    );
  }
}

export { SampleController as default };
```

Comment: removing forceupdate() didn't help with the issue of API not getting triggered when orderType is changed on the UI

Comment: I misunderstood your question (although you don't need `forceUpdate()` anyways). So, you want to call `load()` each time `orderType` is changed? In that case you should use the `componentDidUpdate` method and call your `load()` there. Will update answer with example.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you please provide me with an example that shows how to use componentDidUpdate and componentWillUpdate in the above context?

Comment: On a second thought, you could also use [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentWillreceiveprops), added an example.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried componentWillReceiveProps, it triggers the API call now, but the latest data is not getting rendered in the table. Table still holds data of the first option selected by the user.

Comment: .then((responseJson) => {
        let order_data = responseJson;
        console.log("responseeeeee is: ", order_data);
        self.setState({data: order_data});


logger statement in the above block is not getting printed in the console.

Comment: Can you try the following? - Call fetch directly, do not assign it to `response_data` and change `self.setState({data: order_data});` to `this.setState({data: order_data});`, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Tried calling fetch directly and also changing self.setState to this.setState, even then latest data is not getting rendered, don't see the control going into this block. I don't see "responseeeeee is" getting logged in the console.
      .then((responseJson) => {
        let order_data = responseJson;
        console.log("responseeeeee is: ", order_data);
        self.setState({data: order_data});
        self.forceUpdate();
      })

Comment: it looks like fetch is an async call, therefore while the API call is running, existing data in state gets rendered, 

Is there a way to make state null or make fetch sync (i.e. to control rendering only after API call completes?

Answer (score 0):

remove this line `this.load(orderType);` from constructor and put it inside `componentDidMount`:

```
constructor(){
 //....
} 

componentDidMount() {
  const orderType = this.props.location.query.orderType;
  this.load(orderType);
}
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but didn't work. Same data is getting rendered again and load function is not getting triggered when orderType changes, load function gets called only one time. this is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `setState` to trigger a rerun/rerender on your component.

From the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly):
[image]